# iOS app often shows a hostname error when viewing user profile

Tags: bug, ios-app

[image]

Often when am trying to click my user profile it shows this error .

Comment: I see you keep using wrong tags. When reporting bugs in the iOS app please use [meta-tag:ios-app] and [meta-tag:bug] only. Don't choose random tags. Thanks.